# PDB files not in the appxbundle

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10-universal, pdb-files, appx, appxmanifest

I am trying to include the PDB files so the Store will provide me with Stack Traces with line numbers along with crash reports.

I made sure to select in Build>Advanced>Debugging Information: pdb-only

Upon Build, the /bin/ has .pdb files.

Then on creating App Packages "Include full PDB symbol files" is selected:

[image: PDB Symbols Checked]

and in .csproj I already have

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
```

Once the packaging is done, if I open

> AppPackages\PROG_Test\PROGUWP2_2.5.4.0_AnyCPU.appxbundle\PROGUWP2_2.5.4.0_AnyCPU.appx\

I can see all files except any of the .pdb.

EDIT:
I have missed another archive within it with 
PROG2_2.5.4.0_AnyCPU.appxsym
that contains PDB files only. I am not sure though why Store does not give the line numbers on crash

Comment: "pdb-only" strips source and line number info from the PDB file.  Change to "full".

Answer (score 3):

MSBuild by default removes all the pdb files during the generation of the appx.

In the "Microsoft Visual Studio\%Version%\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\%Version%\AppxPackage" folder, open "Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets" and change the "AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols" value to "true".

```
<AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols Condition="'$(AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols)' == ''">true</AppxPackageIncludePrivateSymbols>
```

The pdb files will now appear in the appx (and of course the appxbundle).

Edit: Microsoft definitly doesn't want us to have pdb in appx, the files are removed for customers after the submission on the Store!

Comment: I found this file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage` and also needed to edit the file as administrator

Comment: I wish I could give 10 up votes.  Been looking for the solution for a day now.  Thank you!!  Also, my path for VS 2022 is at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage

Answer (score -2):

The .pdb file can be found here: "\bin[Platform]\Release\ilc\"

Comment: The pdb is already in \bin\ but they are not in that folder once it is packaged as ppxupload or .appxbundle. The \ilc\ does not exist there

Comment: I get the pdb from the folder above for uploading to HockeyApp to symbolicate the exceptions.  MS describes creating your own appxupload to ensure they are in there here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps . It is under the "To create your app package upload file manually"